# Need help: Creating Abstract, Parametric, Organic Forms Inspired by a Starting Model

Tags: modeling

I have searched the entire internet but I can't find what I'm looking for. It's either always these tessellate, tissue, decimate, voronoi approaches that all look somewhat the same and too uniform and unexciting, or it's completely abstract approaches that produce totally deformed shapes and don't really represent anything figurative. I want to create abstract, parametric, organic forms that are still based on a starting model, just like in the examples. Also, I don't just want a shell but an abstract object that is partially visible as in the examples but also filled with abstract volumes. I hope this is understandable... can anyone help? Thanks in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uiUD.png)[image]

Comment: Look in to using Geometry nodes - specifically _Shortest Edge Path_ - there are some good videos about it (roots, trees, veins, cables) - this is one of them that might suit you - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7yz_0tsTwwM - see if you can adapt the method to your needs.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Sorry i changed the title. Hope it suits the purpose more now.